# mysqldump and powershell produces utf-16

Tags: mysql, shell, powershell, powershell-5.0

When I dump my databases using mysqldump in powershell the shell is producing a UTF-16 file.

How do I stop this behavior and have powershell produce a UTF-8 file (by default)?

Edit: creating a UTF-16 file is causing a "--binary-mode" problem when I try to reload it.

(I'm a powershell noob)

Comment: `start mysqldump "Arguments" -NoNewWindow -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput filename.sql`

Answer (score 4):

> How do I stop this behavior and have powershell produce a UTF-8 file (by default)?

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
```

The question is (As you aren't showing), how do you create a dump?

I assume you're doing it the following way:

```
mysqldump -parameter1 -parameterB > myFile.sql
```

Where it easily could be

```
mysqldump -parameter1 -parameterB | Out-File myFile.sql -Encoding utf8
```

Yes, it's more code to write, but it's not mandatory to change the default behavior.